# Starting with existing database on Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have been enjoying working on [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/) for a while now, and am planning to move a fairly large project to Laravel 5.

The new project has fairly large database with numerous tables, and it would take considerable amount of time build migrations, models and controllers individually.

Has anybody worked on this before? What is the best way to go about it?

I have used this great [extension](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator) to generate migrations as of now - but still for a 200+ tables, it would take quite a long time to do the rest.

Answer (score 6):

Try this one:
https://github.com/reliese/laravel

Reliese Laravel is a collection of Laravel Components which aim is to help the development process of Laravel applications by providing some convenient code-generation capabilities.

Comment: please describe the proposed solution (the link may become invalid, in the future)

Answer (score 4):

How about this: http://packalyst.com/packages/package/ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator

> Model generator Laravel 5 model generator for an existing schema.
>
> It plugs into your existing database and generates model class files
>   based on the existing tables.

Answer (score 0):

For migrating models and controllers just use `artisan` commands, you can't get around it any easier than that. For the migrations I can suggest trying to use the following package:

> [Laravel Database Exporter](https://github.com/nWidart/DbExporter)

It will export your existing DB schemas as Laravel migrations. My suggestion is based on the assumption that you are using MySQL as your RDBMS, because the package I suggested only works with that.

Comment: Thank you, but how to generate models? write them all and run manually?

Comment: The models you'll need to generate yourself, one by one, and setup any [Eloquent Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships) manually. There's no way around that because no tool can guess which tables need to have accompanying models. You can generate models using `artisan make:model ModelName --no-migration` (the option `--no-migration` is there to avoid duplicate DB migration files being generated, since the DbExporter will be responsible for that part).